# How to implement "Exactly once" kafka consumer using Apache Kafka?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-camel, spring-camel

We have an application which consumes messages from Kafka topic ( 3 partitions) and enriches the data and saves the record in DB ( Spring JPA) and then publishes a messages out to another kafka topic (on the same broker) and all of this orchestrated by using Camel 2.4.1 and Spring Boot 2.1.7.RELEASE.

We would like to implement the "exactly-once" semantics for the kafka consumer-producer combination.

Consumer settings:

```
   autoOffsetReset: earliest
   autoCommitEnable: false
   allowManualCommit: true
   breakOnFirstError: true
   group.id : CONSUMER.GROUP.ID
   count: 3
   max.poll.records = 1  # rollback when message processing fails.
```

Producer settings:

```
   idempotence: true
   transactionIdPrefix: txn-prefix-id
```

Bean Wiring:

```
   @Bean
    SpringTransactionPolicy springTransactionPolicy() throws Exception {
        SpringTransactionPolicy txRequired = new SpringTransactionPolicy();
        txRequired.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
        txRequired.setPropagationBehaviorName("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED");
        return txRequired;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> producerFactory() {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> defaultKafkaProducerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]>(
                kafkaConfigs());
        // enable transaction manager
        defaultKafkaProducerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix(transactionIdPrefix);
        return defaultKafkaProducerFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<byte[], byte[]> transactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<>(kafkaTransactionManager(),jpaTransactionManager());
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager kafkaTransactionManager() {
        KafkaTransactionManager<byte[], byte[]> kafkaTransactionManager = new KafkaTransactionManager<>(producerFactory);
        kafkaTransactionManager.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
        kafkaTransactionManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
        return kafkaTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

Camel Route:

```
public RoutesBuilder inboundRoute() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                //Common error handler
                onException(UnsupportedMessageTypeException.class).
                   maximumRedeliveries(redeliveryCount).
                   handled(true).
                   bean(ExceptionPropagatorProcessor.class, "process").
                   bean(manualCommitProcessor).
                end();

                onException(AppRuntimeException.class).
                   maximumRedeliveries(redeliveryCount).                
                   bean(ExceptionPropagatorProcessor.class, "process")
                end();  

                onException(RetryExhaustedException.class).
                   maximumRedeliveries(0).// No retry for this exception
                   handled(true).
                   bean(ExceptionPropagatorProcessor.class, "process").
                   bean(kafkaManualCommitProcessor).
                end(); 

                from("kafka:inboundTopic").
                    routeId("consume-msg").
                    transacted("springTransactionPolicy").
                               bean(transactionBeginProcessor).
                               //check if this is a retry scenario, the max retry count reached then throw RetryExhaustedException.
                               bean(retryEvaluationProcessor). 
                               bean(enrichProcessor). // publish kafka messages
                               bean(persistenceProcessor).
                               bean(transactionEndProcessor). // publish kafka messages
                    bean(manualCommitProcessor);
```

But we are not able to get the kafka producer to commit messages when there are exception handled scenario. What I am missing, and what is the correct approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Spring Kafka and their KafkaTransactionManager is not a real XA capable transaction manager (see their docs for limitations), so you cannot use it for rollback for both Kafka and a JDBC database etc.

And camel-kafka does not support Kafka transactions (yet). I have create a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-15016